# Is there an easy way to monitor sessions in a tomcat web application?

Tags: web-applications, session, tomcat, monitoring

I'm working on a web application using Spring MVC 2.5.  I'm using Eclipse as my IDE and deploying to Tomcat 6.

I'm concerned that I don't understand how sessions work in Spring, and was wondering how I might go about monitoring session status.  I know that Tomcat has various monitoring capabilities, and I can even turn them on in Eclipse...but I don't know how they work.  I also think that I might be able to use the Tomcat manager application, but it doesn't seem to be running.

Anyhow, I don't want to spend the next two days configuring this.  Can someone point me at a simple setup to do monitor sessions?

Answer (score 1):

The Tomcat Manager is the simplest way in all reality.  Unless you have some custom tomcat installation, the manager is always running if tomcat is.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be running when I start Tomcat from Eclipse.  I can see the manager in webapps, but cannot connect.

Comment: No, when I start and stop via Eclipse it only loads the context for my project.

Answer (score 1):

SpringSource (Spring Framework/Rod Johnson guys) has a version of tomcat where they have put all the additional instrumentation into Tomcat

http://www.springsource.com/products/tcserver

> SpringSource tc Server™ is an
>   enterprise version of Apache Tomcat,
>   the widely used web application
>   server.  SpringSource tc Server is
>   hardened for enterprise use and is
>   coupled with key operational
>   capabilities, advanced diagnostics and
>   is backed by mission-critical support.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to see in the session.

If you're interested in what objects are put into the session then I would add a breakpoints on session.get/set/removeAttribute and then debug. You can also add a HttpSessionListener and set breakpoints or log when the session is created/destroyed.

Another way to go is to add opensymphony/clickstream (just a jar and some jsp:s, not a separate webapp). This way you can monitor all activity (clickpaths) for each session. It's easy to modify to also show all session attributes. (google opensymphony clickstream)